# How to copy resources in maven in the jar of a different module

Tags: java, maven

I have the following module structure in a java project

-Root 
-- Main-Module 
-- Another Module

And using maven-resources-plugin , im trying to copy some resources that exist in *Main Module* into *Another Module*

Using the below snippet in the pom.xml of **Main Module** i run mvn clean install, therefore basedir is the base dir of Main Module.

```
<execution>
    <id>copy-resources-json2</id>
    <phase>process-resources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${session.executionRootDirectory}/Another-Module/src/main/resources/config</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/config</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

While it does copy the resources locally in the project, the **problem** is, when i check the jar of **Another Module** the resources are not present in the config directory.

What am i doing wrong please.

Comment: Never do this! If you need the resources in another module move them into the other module...

Comment: @khmarbaise i understand its bad practice, however in this case i have no option, any suggestions on how to do the copy?

Comment: No option? Why it's simply wrong. It will cause many issues. And state the reason why you need to copy resources from one module to another... ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a better practice to move the Maven config files to the Module you want to use them.

But if you have a structure like this:

```
.
 |-- my-module
 |   `-- pom.xml
 `-- parent
     `-- pom.xml
```

Maybe you want to structure your pom.xml with relative paths like this:

```
<project>
...
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
...
</project>
```

You can check the examples of pom structures in the [Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html).

Comment: What will the relative path help here? Apart from that it's also bad practise.. Move the parent element to the parent directory so you can omit the relative path completely. (Follow convention over configuration!!)